# Redefining Xamarin.Forms.Color

Tags: xamarin.forms, colors

Is there any way to redefine the colours available on Xamarin.Forms to my own specific colours? Like for instance, I would like to redefine purple as the hex code 8d198f. This is because I make use of the same colour in numerous places and would find it easier if I could just use the "Color.Purple" in place of the same hex code everywhere.

Thanks for reading and appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that AFAIK, What you can do on the Contrary is maintain the same in the in your App.Xaml and use them where ever you need

**App.Xaml**

```
<Color x:Key="Purple">#8d198f</Color>
```

And use it like below:

**Xaml**

```
SomeColor="{StaticResource Purple}"
```

**C#**

```
SomeColor= (Color)Application.Current.Resources["Purple"];
```